# PhpStorm jump to remote file

Tags: deployment, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I know there is a function to jump in the "remote tab" from the current local file I am editing. Does anybody know the name, so I can find it in the Keymap options.

Sometimes it is useful to just edit it on the server and test it, instead of uploaded all the changes.

Comment: *"Sometimes it is useful to just edit it on the server and test it, instead of uploaded all the changes."* It works exactly the same -- just in case of Remote Edit IDE will download file and keep it outside of the project and will forget about it once you close editor tab (so file will not be kept as part of the project). You still have to confirm that you wish to upload the file to remote as (AFAIK) it does not happen automatically.

Comment: BTW -- did you know that with local files you can always setup automatic upload on save ... so once file is saved it's automatically uploaded? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm

Comment: *"I know there is a function to jump in the "remote tab" from the current local file I am editing."* You mean `Navigate | Select In... | Remote Host` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the menu `Navigate` > `Select in...` or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> or on [MacOs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Keymaps_Comparison_Mac.html#top_shortcuts) <kbd>⌥F1</kbd>

[image: navigation menu]

When you choose this, a popup will appear where you can choose Remote Host or hit <kbd>3</kbd>

[image: popup of jump target selection]